# how to get children of a notebook in gtk using C

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I have a gtk window that contains a notebook. I want to get the children of the same. I am using following statement 
`GList *children;
 notebook = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (self->gui, "list_notebook"));
 children = gtk_container_get_childern (GTK_CONTAINER (notebook));`

I am getting the following error while compiling

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_container_children’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Show at least the lines around the line where this error occurs. You probably forgot to include the header file where `gtk_container_children` is declared.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i am getting error on this function. Its an in built in gtk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gtk_container_children()` has been deprecated for a *very* long time and is not part of the GTK+ 3 API. Whatever component is using that macro needs to be updated to use [`gtk_container_get_children()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-get-children).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This function will only give non internal children i guess. I want internal children actually

Comment: Yes, it returns non-internal children just like `gtk_container_children()` used to... The reference documentation points you to the right solution for internal children.